# Can I read using an analog pin on an arduino Mega whether or not there is a high (5v) voltage on a wire from another board's digital pin?

Tags: communication, analogread, wires, digital

I am making a peer-to-peer network of initiating devices and a common hub, which controls most of the hardware. It sends a number over `Serial` to Mega's `Serial1` (Mega's `Serial` is used for communicating to the computer), but as a fallback it initiates a general alarm by sending a 5v signal (using `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)`) to the main board. In order to complete the circuit and get the read, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what you ask is purpose of a digital pin. to read a state of a digital pin of some other device

Comment: 5V is a value of `voltage`, not a value of `current` .... please edit the title of your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can. Better to use `digitalRead()` than `analogRead()` however.

You just need to tie the grounds of the 2 Arduinos together, and set up the pin on the Arduino you want to sense the input as INPUT or INPUT_PULLUP. Then do a digitalRead on the pin. It will return `LOW` if the other Arduino is setting the pin LOW, and `HIGH` if the other Arduino is setting it HIGH.

And, as Juraj points out in their comment, CMOS devices like Arduinos respond to voltage, not current. Their inputs are capacitive. They react to a voltage potential, not current. (When you initially change a CMOS input from one state to another a small amount of current flows in to change the state of the capacitor and after that the only current that flows is a **very** tiny amount of leakage current through the capacitor on the input.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I would not have thought of this myself. I'd have gone to the ends of the Earth over-engineering some code to beam signals off the moon and back just to say "HEY" to the other board lmao.

Comment: @duncan-c, you should not suggest in an answer on Arduino SE that LOW is  false and HIGH is true.

Comment: @Juraj, why shouldn't you suggest this? In my experience, we use switches that are normally open when in normal state, so closing them and closing a HIGH voltage would signify the change.

Comment: @WinterfromSYGMAH  `HIGH` / `true`, and `LOW` / `false` are different constants, and should not be used interchangeably. Juarj is correct. I edited my post.

Comment: @DuncanC and Juraj, thank you for the clarification and the help

Comment: formally, you should always write `digitalRead(pin) == LOW` or `digitalRead(pin) == HIGH` to check the state. there is no warranty that the value of `LOW` is 0 on all Arduino architectures. there could be some strange MCU package somewhere :-)